# Hive Converting from Double to String Not in Scientific

Tags: hive

I have a table with a column double type, and I am trying to convert that from double to string.

However, when I use the cast command, it "smartly" convert that into scientific notation.  like below:

```
select 
    number, 
    cast(number as string), 
from ...
```

it looks like

```
number     c1_
9999999902  9.999999902E9
9999999902  9.999999902E9
9999999902  9.999999902E9
9999999902  9.999999902E9
9999999909  9.999999909E9
```

Can anyone show me how to avoid converting that into scientific and keep the raw text?

Comment: `cast(cast(number as BIGINT) as STRING)` maybe?

Comment: DOUBLE is evil. Whatever the database you are using (Hive, Oracle, MySkull, etc) it is evil. With DOUBLEs, 999.99+0.01-1000 is not equal to zero. Use it only as a last resort, when you have absolutely no clue of the scale and precision of your data, and provision for verbose code to handle rounding errors. ===> Starting with Hive 0.13 you can use the DECIMAL(x,y) data type, at long last :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hive converts double to scientific representation while cast to string because Hive treats double itself in a same way. Therefore, problem is not with cast to string.

See below example:

```
 select 9999999902.0, cast(9999999902.0 as BIGINT), cast(cast(9999999902.0 as BIGINT)  as string) from ..
```

Output:

```
OK
9.999999902E9   9999999902
```

Answer (score 13):

Hive supports good old `printf()` function so that you can control the output format *explicitly* - check [Language Manual UDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) under "String functions"

Comment: printf('%.2f',data_column)  helpded

Comment: Thanks for actually providing the answer to the problem!