# in hive casting of decimal to double is returning the exponential form rather than the non scientific form

Tags: hadoop, casting, hive

in hive casting of decimal to double is returning the exponential form rather than the non scientific form

Example

```
hive> select cast(12345678910.231 as double);
OK
1.2345678910231E10
Time taken: 0.164 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

but need the value 12345678910.231 stored as double.

`select cast(cast(12345678910.231 as double) as double);` also wont work and is similar as the above.

I dont need the output format to be change using the prontf() UDF, rather i need the value to be stored and retrieved while querying as a non exponential form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive Converting from Double to String Not in Scientific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576187/hive-converting-from-double-to-string-not-in-scientific)