# Select using NVL wrote letters. Why?

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark-sql

I wrote this select:

```
    SELECT 
    nvl(SUM(vl_item),0)     AS SUM_VALOR_ITENS
   ,nvl(SUM(vl_discount),0) AS SUM_VALOR_DESCONTO
   ,nvl(SUM(qty_item) is null   ,0,0)    AS SUM_QTD_ITENS
   ,COUNT(DISTINCT cod_product_rms) AS QTD_ITENS_UNICOS
   FROM db.my_table
   where SAFRA = 202006
```

When I ran on DBeaver, the result was 0 (zero), like I expected.
But, the result when I ran this SQL in a HQL file using Java was "0E-10", "0E-18" and "0E-18" respectively.
I don't understand why I received this result.
Somebody can help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hive Converting from Double to String Not in Scientific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576187/hive-converting-from-double-to-string-not-in-scientific)

Comment: Hive is converting  double to scientific representation

Comment: Ok, I understand now. The question  now is: How can include a treatment to convert the NULL value in zero integer (or decimal)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using coalesce, nvl will not work for the 3rd column, as NVL only takes 2 arguments (this one takes 3), whereas coalesce can take as many as you wish.

```
    SELECT 
    coalesce(SUM(vl_item),0)     AS SUM_VALOR_ITENS
   ,coalesce(SUM(vl_discount),0) AS SUM_VALOR_DESCONTO
   ,coalesce(SUM(qty_item) is null   ,0,0)    AS SUM_QTD_ITENS
   ,COUNT(DISTINCT cod_product_rms) AS QTD_ITENS_UNICOS
   FROM db.my_table
   where SAFRA = 202006
```